# Can´t install GNU Screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

My current RePo is:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

but if i try to install GNU Screen this happens:

```
sudo apt-get install screen

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package screen is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'screen' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Also unavailable are `byobu` and `tmux`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try and run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Make sure all packages update. I just had an issue where they weren't updating completely. Once they finished, I was able to install screen.